# How to improve this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

The plan:

```
                   |  month 1          month 7          month 13          month 19 
Sharing sessions   |  seminar          workshop         seminar           workshop
```

Can I express the above planning as below, if not, how to improve?

There are four sharing sessions, comprising two seminars and two workshops, are planned; one in every six months.

Comment: Those are not each six months apart (they are 5, 6, and 12 months apart), and your sentence is awkward.

Comment: Without major changes, it could be, "There are four sharing sessions comprising of two seminars and two workshops, planned one every six months."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double-verb makes this sentence at least awkward (There are ... are planned). How about:

Four sharing sessions are planned, one every six months; the first is a seminar and then they alternate with a workshop.

or

Four sharing sessions are planned, one every six months: seminar, workshop, seminar, workshop.